# Android ServerSocket Port Selection

Tags: java, android, sockets, port, serversocket

I'm trying to figure out how the Android OS assigns ports via the ServerSocket constructor.

(**Link:** http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html)

Specifically, using the 2nd constructor, the documentation claims that "*If port == 0, a port will be assigned by the OS*." Does anyone know how this port is assigned by the Android OS? Based on running a significant amount of **netstat -a** commands on the Android terminal, it appears to be a random selection.

Can anyone confirm this? I'd like to know what I can expect when a 0 is entered for this parameter.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't know the specifics, but seeing as Android is Linux underneath, this may be informative: https://idea.popcount.org/2014-04-03-bind-before-connect/#port-allocation

Answer (score 1):

As per [java documentation](http://download.java.net/jdk7/archive/b123/docs/api/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)):

> A port number of 0 means that the port number is automatically
>   allocated, typically from an ephemeral port range.

[Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/net/ServerSocket.html#ServerSocket(int)) suggests that OS chooses the port for you:

> If port == 0, a port will be assigned by the OS

Basically it will choose a random *free* port.

Some extra: [This site](http://www.iana.org/assignments/service-names-port-numbers/service-names-port-numbers.xhtml) that contains a list of ports and service who use it.

Comment: It will choose a random port that is not in use already. Nothing 'open' about it.

Comment: @EJP yep, my bad. Should have wrote free.